# iframe created twice with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, click, attr

I am using two links on a page to create an iframe each.
The problem is that it is creating the iframe twice.

I did use each link id to check weather it is loading one iframe for each link but the iframe that loads twice has the same id.

```
<a id="mylink12" href="anyurl">My link one</a>
<a id="mylink13" href="somedifferenturl"> My link two</a>

jQuery(".editme").click(function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var editid = 'frame-'+jQuery(this).attr('id');
                        var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                            if(jQuery(editid).size() == 0) {
                                jQuery('<iframe />', {
                                    name: 'frame',
                                    id:   editid,
                                    src: url
                                }).appendTo('#here');  
                            };
                        return false;
                }).once();
```

Not sure why.

Comment: Where is `.editme` and `#here`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of problem is in this line:

```
if(jQuery(editid).size() == 0)
```

You have to prepend `editid` with `'#'` string if you want to find element by `id` attr. Otherwise `editid` will be treated as a tag name (`frame-*`).

So this line should be changed to:

```
if(jQuery('#'+editid).size() == 0)
```

Comment: Exactly, I was just trying to remove the class to see if it would do the trick but was making the same mistake.